# Android TableLayout Design for news feed

Tags: android, android-layout, tablelayout, android-tablelayout

I am currently developing a news feed-like activity in my Android application (I am quite new to Android development).

[The following picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uxfNI.png) shows an example of what I am trying to achieve.
To sum-up:

- A list of news
- For each piece of news, left column displays a picture (size is the same for each piece of news), right column displays a right bubble to display date, titles and first lines of the linked article.

Back-end communication was easy to set-up, I receive a list of news on a separate thread and use UI thread to update the view.
Unfortunately view formatting is not so easy for me.
I tried several solutions mixing TableLayout & RelativeLayouts.
Unfortunately, none of these solutions was efficient.

At this stage, I got stuck with rows that are bigger than screen width ([like in this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0VBfc.png)

To build my layout, I use 2 XMLs & use code to update text values and pictures.

First XML contains TableLayout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:stretchColumns="1"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
    android:id="@+id/tblFeed">

</TableLayout>
```

Second XML contains Table Row pattern:

```
<TableRow xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:stretchColumns="1"
    android:id="@+id/tblRow">

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"  android:paddingLeft="0dp"
    android:paddingRight="0dp"
    android:paddingTop="0dp"
    android:paddingBottom="0dp">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:padding="3dip"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/imgPin"
        android:src="@drawable/android_icon"/>
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:paddingLeft="0dp"
    android:paddingRight="0dp"
    android:paddingTop="0dp"
    android:paddingBottom="0dp">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
    android:padding="3dip"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textSize="18sp"
        android:gravity="right"
    android:id="@+id/txtDate"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
    android:padding="3dip"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:id="@+id/txtType"
    android:layout_below="@+id/txtDate"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
    android:padding="3dip"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:id="@+id/txtTitle"
    android:layout_below="@+id/txtType"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
    android:padding="3dip"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:id="@+id/txtDescription"
    android:layout_below="@+id/txtTitle"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

I am stuck with several problems:

- picture is not centered in the row
- text view in second column is bigger than screen

I am also wondering if mixing TableLayouts & RelativeLayouts is really the best way to achieve this.

Can you please advise?

Comment: I don't think a TableLayout is what you want. That's for a grid of columns and rows. I think you'd be better off working with a ListView. It will just provide you a list of rows of info on the screen that you can then customize with your own layout with images, text, etc.

Comment: @drschultz I followed your suggestion using a ListView instead of a TableLayout and... everything works very well! :)

Comment: Great to hear it! You'll also want to familiarize yourself with the `RecyclerView` which is essentially a more flexible version of `ListView`.

Answer (score -1):

You shouldn't use a TableLayout. Instead, use a RelativeLayot normally. And for those cards with news#1 and news#2, use [CardView](http://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html#CardView)